# Pass parameter and ng-click to the angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to pass some data from HTML to the directive, also this directive should be clickable by ng-click.
Question is how i can pass parameter of link function to the template?

```js
app.directive("hello", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template : '<button  ng-click="updateModel()">'+attrs.name+'</button>',
    scope : {},
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
      scope.updateModel = function(){
        console.log("yay");
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Here is HTML directive: `<hello name="john"></hello>`

Comment: you should use scope for this and also bind click event to directive.

Comment: @Phil Thanks, It's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method

JS

```
app.directive("hello", function(){
      return {
        restrict: "E",
        template : '<button  ng-click="updateModel()" >{{name}}</button>',
        scope : {
            name :"@",
            user :"="
        },
        link : function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
          scope.updateModel = function(){
            console.log(scope.name, scope.user);
          }
        }
      };
    });
```

HTML

```
<hello name="jimbrooism" user="user"></hello>
```

1. = is two-way binding
2. @ simply reads the value (one-way binding)
3. & is used to bind functions

Comment: Thanks Jim. Now how to pass modal or objects in parameter of directive? for ex: <hello name="hello {{user}}"></hello>

Comment: No. I mean `{{user}}` inside of name parameter. ex: `name="jimbrooism {{user}}"`

Comment: name="'jimbrooism'+{{user}}" try this

Comment: name="jimbrooism123 {{pages}}" working as a parameter

Comment: @nisar no doesn't work. it's empty when DOM render finished.

Comment: <hello ng-if="user" name="jimbrooism" user="user"></hello> try this

Comment: @Jimbrooism Still not working! it's blank when DOM render finish.

Answer (score 1):

look:

```
app.directive("hello", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template : '<button  ng-click="updateModel()">{{name}}</button>',
    scope : {
      name: "@"
    },
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
      scope.updateModel = function(){
        console.log("yay");
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/da8eHrxaxZsZm731b0Uk

Comment: Thanks Diego. Now how to pass modal in parameter of directive? for ex: `<hello name="hello {{user.john}}"></hello>` .

Comment: Model or maybe objects.

Comment: No. I mean Modal in parameter. name is parameter, now how pass modal or objects in this parameter? It is possible?